# How to run bottle server with multiple ports

Tags: python, server, port, bottle

I'm trying to run a bottle server such that some routes run on one port, and the others run on another port.

However, reading through the documentation has proved no fruits: https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/bottle-docs.pdf.

Is this possible with bottle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not route to multiple ports.
A server needs an address and a port to listen to. So, routing will be done after address and port are set in server.

Comment: Is it possible to run multiple servers on different ports in parallel that reference the same state?

Comment: @henrywallace Yes, you can but they can not reference to the same state (can not share memory).